# Google App Maker: date-driven email notifications

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-app-maker

I need to set up email notifications when the current date is 90, 60, and 30 days from an expiration date.

I've solved the problem (know basically what process is necessary) but am struggling to write the code.  :/

Here's what I've pieced together from research. I think it's probably close, but I'm sure it's not correct.

Suggestions? Solutions?

```
    function sendAlerts() {
  var query = app.models.Customers.newQuery();
  var today = new Date();
  var expiresOn = new Date();

  // query only for non-notified customers with upcoming due date
  query.filters.NotificationAttempts._lessThan = ATTEMPTS_THRESHOLD;
  query.filters.Notified._equals = false;
  query.filters.DueDate._lessThan = expiresOn;

  var customers = query.run();

  customers.forEach(function(customer) {
    var success = sendNotification(customer);

    if (success) {
      customer.Notified = true;
    } else {
      customer.NotificationAttempts++;
    }

    // performance trade off in favor of consistency
    app.saveRecords([customer]);
  });


function sendNotification_(to, subject, body)
      {
        MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: 'beth@egaassociates.com',
          subject: 'Expiration approaching',
          body: 'You have a license, certification, or immunization expiring soon!',
          noReply: true
        });
       }
}

/**
 * Creates a time-driven trigger.
 */
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  // Trigger on set schedule.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendAlerts')
      .timeBased()
      .everyMinutes(2)
      .create();
}

google.scripts.run.createTimeDrivenTriggers();
```

Comment: Where and how are you running the function to create the trigger? With App Maker you essentially have to call the server function to create the trigger from your client somewhere and this would need to happen for each of your deployments and your 'Preview'. After testing, I would suggest removing the trigger again otherwise it will continue running it from each of deployments as well as your 'Preview'. Have you actually run your trigger to test it? I don't see an immediate problem with your code, so I would suggest actually running your code first. For testing I would change the frequency.

Comment: I have all of this code currently in the App Maker scripts area (inside the app I've put together.) I've found info on creating triggers outside of the app you're working in, but it all applies to Google Sheets. Can you clarify?

Comment: You actually need to call the function createTimeDrivenTriggers() from like a button in the UI by doing `google.scripts.run.createTimeDrivenTriggers()`. Otherwise all you have is the function but the trigger will actually never be created. Then you should also have a button in the UI that will delete the trigger.

Comment: Hm, ok thank you. Why is it necessary to delete the trigger? We're trying to make this process (checking for upcoming expirations) as automatic as possible.

Comment: You would delete the trigger if it by chance would no longer be needed, or as stated during testing periods you don't want the trigger to stay active on a test deployment or in your 'Preview' because it would continually run until it is deleted. So even if your trigger function does not actually process any records, your project would still invoke the function thereby consuming resources against your project. I would suggest looking at the App Maker sample app for triggers if you have not already. https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/triggers

Comment: Ok thank you so much.

Comment: Markus, do you mind taking another look at this? I cannot get it to 'do' anything (at all), even after changing the frequency, and I cannot see where I've gone wrong or what is missing.

Comment: I did add this email function before the time driven trigger:

function sendEmailCreated_(to, subject, body)
      {
        MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: 'beth@egaassociates.com',
          subject: 'Expiration approaching',
          body: 'You have a license, certification, or immunization expiring soon!',
          noReply: true
        });
       }

Comment: Did you run the createTimeDrivenTriggers() function yet? Without actually running that function, the trigger does not get created, so that is an important step. Then depending on the frequency you assigned in the create trigger function you may just need to wait to see if your trigger functions. That is why I would typically suggest testing triggers at a relatively high frequency like every couple of minutes but then immediately deleting the trigger again especially with email sending since that will count against your quota.

Comment: I did add the run command, with no luck. I've updated the code here to show what I currently have.

Comment: Did you add the google.script.run on the server script? If that’s the case that won’t work. It needs to be called from the client. For testing purposes I would add a button somewhere in your UI and add that code to the button on click event.

Comment: I do have it in the server script. hm.

So, does that mean that this cannot be fully automated, just running on a set schedule and generating the email notifications? It has to be kicked off manually in the UI?

And - doesn't that then make the time driven trigger useless? I'm not understanding.

Comment: You are missing an important concept here. App Maker does not have a command line interface to be able to run the create trigger function. Therefore, you have to run the function via google.script.run one time from the client to actually create the trigger. Once you have done this, the trigger is part of your project and will continually run automatically. Then the only time the trigger would need to be kicked off manually is if you were to delete it and needed to be created again. Have you checked out the example application for this?

Comment: Ok, yes, I did not know that. I have gone through many / most of the sample apps, but have not seen anything like this. I'll go look through them more carefully.

Comment: See my previous comment on the example app. It has a link to where the application can be loaded directly to your G Drive.

Comment: Thank you for your input and patience, Markus. I'll have to get someone to handle this task.